# How to check if UILabel isEnabled?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

The UILabel has the ability to setEnabled: which works great. But how in the blazes can I find out later on if the label is enabled?

The Apple docs say that there is a getter (isEnabled), but it isn't being recognized as a valid accessor...

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code, and any error messages. `isEnabled` should work.

Comment: What is the issue with `isEnabled`? How are you using it?

Comment: You're all right. I wasn't referencing my tableViewCell correctly...DOH!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this.

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lbl.enabled = YES;
//     lbl.enabled = NO;
if (lbl.isEnabled)
{
    NSLog(@"Enabled");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Not Enabled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying `label.isEnabled`, change that to `label.enabled` or `[label isEnabled]`.

In Objective-C, `BOOL` properties are by convention named and accessed that way.